# Subconsulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou fazendo a consulta abaixo:

```
select idtce 
from tab_tce
where idempresa = 2493 
and YEAR(dt_inicial) = 2018
and idtce not in(
select TCE_ID
from SEC_VAGA_ESTUDANTE
)
```

Porém retorna esse erro:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.
```

O que tem de errado com minha consulta?

Comment: De errado nada, só tá informando que tem valores duplicados na consulta e como você está usando igualdades o banco não pode listar todas as informações

Comment: Eu quero excluir da consulta principal os resultados que coincidem com o campo idtce na subconsulta, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não daria para fazer um join ao invés da sub-consulta, assim retiraria os replicados no where.

Comment: esse erro acontece quando você retorna mais de um valor na subquery, e na clausula do `where` está usando por exemplo "=", com o `in` isso não deveria acontecer porque o `in` espera uma lista de valores, a query está exatamente igual ao que colocou na pergunta?

Comment: duas coisas que pode fazer para resolver: 1) substituir o `in` por um `not exists`  2) como quer que o valor não esteja na outra tabela, pode fazer por exemplo um `LEFT OUTER` para validar isso

Comment: Fiz uma edição na query. Agora retorna uma lista vazia mas pelo menos funciona.

Comment: Oi, amigo não deu erro. Sua consulta está apenas retornando valores duplicados. Aconselho fortemente você fazer essa consulta através de um *[join](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006)*.
Da uma olhada no link.

Comment: @JoãoIgnácio Se o código tem 8 linhas como é que a mensagem de erro está na linha 9?

Comment: Simples, não comecei a consulta na linha 1. Pois tinha outras consultas na query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei fazendo assim:

```
select * 
from tab_tce tce 
left join SEC_VAGA_ESTUDANTE sec
on tce.idtce = sec.TCE_ID
where YEAR(dt_inicial) = 2018
and idempresa = 2493
and sec.TCE_ID is null
```